# How can I apply advanced Excel formatting when using Kendo UI for jQuery Grid Excel Export, such as repeating headers & footers, orientation, margins?

Tags: jquery, excel, kendo-ui

I'm trying to export an Excel file from a grid, using Kendo UI for jQuery. There is some limited formatting that is built-in, like bold, underline, insert row, etc.

I need to set the orientation, margins, and Excel Header and Footer values that repeat on every page when printed.

Here is an example of the export functionality. https://dojo.telerik.com/ELiMA

Is there an API or JavaScript snippet out there I could use to force this functionality?